# DevExpress NavBar: Appearance has no effect

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, skinning, navbar

this question is fairly DevExpress-specific.

I use a NavBar control with the standard "SkinExplorerBarView" in a WinForms app, and **would like to change the appearance of a selected navigation link**.

I changed the background color of the control's "ItemPressed" and "ItemActive" appearances, as well as each single item's "Pressed" appearance, but **none of these had the any effect on how the links look like when I click on them**.

I also tried to set the control's LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel property to False, but that didn't help neither.

As proposed by Rusty, I then tried to implement the CustomDrawLink event, still without success. (Funnily, after having selected a link, it doesn't have the state "Selected" but "Pressed" instead, so I used that):

```
private void nbcNavigation_CustomDrawLink(object sender, 
    DevExpress.XtraNavBar.ViewInfo.CustomDrawNavBarElementEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ObjectInfo.State == DevExpress.Utils.Drawing.ObjectState.Pressed)
    {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 255);
    }
}
```

I found [an example](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XtraNavBar/DevExpressXtraNavBarNavBarControl_CustomDrawLinktopic.htm) on using CustomDrawLink, but that does all the drawing by hand, which is much pain and overkill. I want the DevExpress "engine" to draw the link, just by using another BackColor.

Comment: "I want the DevExpress "engine" to draw the link, just by using another BackColor."....It will not do this...."...but that does all the drawing by hand, which is much pain.." Yes it is much pain and is the only way to do what you want with  the current DevX release. Sorry.

Comment: Hi Rusty, I see. This is really disappointing and I wouldn't have expected that from DevExpress, but I guess I'll have to put up with it...

Comment: Make sure you post your needs on the DevX site...they are better than most in responding to customer requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NavBar is a real pain to customize ... mostly because it is designed to give a common appearance for all navigation items (style police, not my idea). You should pick one of the skin styles that works best with your Gui (getting to know the skin/lookandfeel system is worth the time).

Then use the CustomDrawXXX events of the NavBar control for any custom painting needs :)

You could also use the DevX skin designer and create a skin just for the NavBar.

Comment: Hi Rusty. I didn't manage yet to use that event appropriately. (Incorporated my code in my question)

Comment: Thanks. Performing the drawing "by hand" as mentioned in my update did it. I cannot vote up your answer because I already did that once, but then thought I should first try it out and undid the voting. Now it says: You already voted... If you slightly modify your answer voting should be unlocked again. ;-)

Comment: Just glad you got the results you needed.